# active directory users have auto-created private user share

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, windows-server-2008, active-directory, wmi

Currently using server 2008 and a logon vbscript to auto mount 3 drives. I'd like to have a mapped network drive that goes to a user-private share automatically. Is this possible to rig up in a login vbscript ?

So when a user logs in I'd like them to see

- s: (employee share drive)
- x: (public share drive)
- u: (private user share
  drive that only user can access) .

I've got it all set up except for the private user share drive, does anyone know how I would go about implementing this? The clients are all running Windows 7 Pro if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

on server 2008, you can map a home drive to the users login via active directory profile setting. it will also give the ownership of that folder to the user so security permissions are set automatically and when you create new users by copying current ones it will create the home folder and set permissions automatically in the same directory on the server as well.

Comment: We use this in our environment. It works very well. The best part is  you can bulk edit a group of users and set their home directory to "\\server\share\%username%" and AD will expand that variable for every user and properly create the folders as Arthur described. But, I read somewhere that this functionality was getting phased out/obsoleted. Does anyone know if that is actually true? Something about Group Policy Preferences being preferred? Not sure, but we just moved to Server 2008R2 and kept our Home Directories because they work so well...

Answer (score 1):

Make a private share on the server, with folders for each user, then map the U: drive to `\\server\share\username`; if you use it as a home drive as Arthur points out Windows can create the directory structure for you and assign permissions. Otherwise you have to create the folders and assign permissions.

Personal plug, I just put an article with a [VBScript drive mapping script](http://stoneyforest.net/~chris/blog/windows/scripts/mapdrives.html).